# Nodejs: How to do String.replace with file content asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
var data = data.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) {
    if (fs.existsSync("./include" + b)) {
        return new String(fs.readFileSync('./include' + b));
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR!: ./include" + a + " not found.");
        return "";
    }
});
```

The code works perfectly. However, existsSync and readFileSync will block the node process.

I can't buffer all the files before hands because it's huge and consume a lot of memory.

I'm looking at promise, but isn't .then() will block the thread?

Is there a way to use fs.readFile in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend not attempting to do this in a single function. Break down what you need to do, especially as async is involved.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// find a list of unique file references
function findFiles (data) {
  const files = {};
  const regex = /{{(.*?)}}/g;
  while ((match = regex.exec(data)) != null) {
    files[match[1]] = true;
  }
  return Object.keys(files);
}

function replaceFile (data, filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(`./include${filePath}`, function (err, fileData) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return resolve(data);
      }
      // we can replace multiple file references without reading
      // the file multiple times.
      const regex = new RegExp('{{' + filePath + '}}', 'g');
      return resolve(data.replace(regex, fileData));
    });
  });
}

// use of reduce to allow us to chain the promises so we modify
// data one file at a time and don't rely on it bing a reference
// which we're modifying.
function replaceFiles (data, filePaths) {
  return filePaths.reduce(
    (promise, filePath) => {
      return promise.then((newData) => {
        return replaceFile(newData, filePath);
      });
    },
    Promise.resolve(data)
  );
}

const data = 'hello {{/file.txt}} {{/file2.txt}} {{/file.txt}} world';

const filePaths = findFiles(data);
console.log({ filePaths });

replaceFiles(data, filePaths)
.then(data => console.log({ data }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably wanting to use `readFile` instead, also could use the error return the check if file exists that way

```
data.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) {
  fs.readFile('./include' + b, (err, fileData) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }

      data = new String(fileData)
  })
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. However, the string's portion that should be replace was replaced with 'undefined' instead of the file content.

Comment: What are you calling replace on? In your code above it seems you are calling it on `data` @BranyaTheGreat

Answer (score 0):

You can go for async function of both `exist()` and `readFile`. However, `exist` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback). It's recommended to use [access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) or [stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) instead.

```
var data = data.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) {

    fs.access("./include" + b, function(err) {
        if (err) {
        // specific "no such file or directory" error code
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT')
                return console.log("ERROR!: ./include" + a + " not found.");
            // throw another error as well          
            throw err;
        }

        fs.readFile('./include' + b, "utf-8", function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                // handle error
            return data;
        });
    });
});
```

However, doing as above it's not recommended as well.

> Using fs.access() to check for the accessibility of a file before
>   calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended.
>   Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change
>   the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should
>   open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the
>   file is not accessible.

---

As recommendation, our code can be modified as:

```
var data = data.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) {

    fs.readFile('./include' + b, "utf-8", function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT')
                return console.log("ERROR!: ./include" + a + " not found.");
            throw err;
        }   
        return data;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. However, the string's portion that should be replace was replaced with 'undefined' instead of the file content.

Comment: I dug a bit deeper. As we want to return as string, we can pass encoding method as argument of `readFile()` which will return data as `string` instead of `buffer`. Edited.

Comment: I don't think it will make any change. Can you console whether the right file is read?

Comment: Yeah, the file was read, but it was read afterward. However, the string.replace()'s callback read the return immediately which the fs.readFile doesn't finish reading the file yet. So it got 'undefined' as the return.